# Howto get multiple data from a custom component to the backend bean?

Tags: jsf-2, input, decode, custom-component

I have a data object called `DeliveryPeriod` which is a container for a start and a end date (saved as `String` like dd.MM.yyy, comes from the database) an the id of another object called `PlanningPeriod`. This delivery period should be displayed in its own custom component in JSF like

`<myc:deliveryPeriodComponent value="#{backendBean.deliveryPeriod}" />`

I implement a class `DeliveryPeriodComponent` which extends `UIInput` and a `DeliveryPeriodComponentRenderer` which `extendes javax.faces.renderer`. The rendering works well, i see two calender elements and a SelectOneMenu to choose the planning period. But render the data is not all, I need to change the data as well. And here comes the problem, i have no idea to get the data inside my component to the backend bean. The `decode()` method did not know the new values and the other methods are never called. I didn't know the trick, how to connect the JSF page to the bean, from the tutorial (http://jsfatwork.irian.at, i bought the book) i had these methods like `getValue()` and `getConverter()`.

Here is the code from the component:

```
public class DeliveryPeriodComponent extends UIInput {

public static final String COMPONENT_TYPE = "de.hacon.tps.integrator.web.component.deliveryperiod.DeliveryPeriodComponent";

enum PropertyKeys {
    begin, end, planningPeriod
}

public DeliveryPeriodComponent() {
    setRendererType("de.hacon.tps.integrator.web.component.deliveryperiod.DeliveryPeriodComponent");
}

public String getBegin() {
    return (String) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.begin, "01.01.2012");
}

public void setBegin(String begin) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.begin, begin);
}

public String getEnd() {
    return (String) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.end, "31.12.2012");
}

public void setEnd(String end) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.end, end);
}

public int getPlanningPeriod() {
    return (Integer) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.planningPeriod, 0);
}

public void setPlanningPeriod(int planningPeriod) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.planningPeriod, planningPeriod);
}}
```

And here is the renderer:

public class DeliveryPeriodComponentRenderer extends Renderer {

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {
    DeliveryPeriodComponent comp = (DeliveryPeriodComponent) component;
    String clientId = comp.getId();
    try {
        encodeInput(context, comp, clientId);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void encodeInput(FacesContext context, DeliveryPeriodComponent comp, String clientId) throws ParseException {
    comp.getChildren().clear();
    DeliveryPeriod value = (DeliveryPeriod) comp.getAttributes().get("value");
    List<PlanningPeriodSubset> pp = (List<PlanningPeriodSubset>) comp.getAttributes().get("periods");

    HtmlPanelGrid pGrid = new HtmlPanelGrid();
    pGrid.setColumns(4);
    Calendar cBegin = new Calendar();
    cBegin.setShowOn("button");
    cBegin.setValue(sdf.parse(value.getStartDate()));
    cBegin.setPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    pGrid.getChildren().add(cBegin);
    Calendar cEnd = new Calendar();
    cEnd.setShowOn("button");
    cEnd.setValue(sdf.parse(value.getEndDate()));
    cEnd.setPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    pGrid.getChildren().add(cEnd);
    HtmlSelectOneMenu sPlanningPeriod = new HtmlSelectOneMenu();

    Collection<UISelectItem> items = new ArrayList<UISelectItem>();
    for (PlanningPeriodSubset op : pp) {
        UISelectItem item = new UISelectItem();
        item.setItemLabel(op.getName());
        item.setItemValue(op.getId());
        items.add(item);
    }

    sPlanningPeriod.getChildren().addAll(items);
    sPlanningPeriod.setValue(value.getPlanningPeriodId());
    pGrid.getChildren().add(sPlanningPeriod);
    HtmlPanelGrid buttonPanel = new HtmlPanelGrid();
    buttonPanel.setColumns(2);
    Button bDelete = new Button();
    bDelete.setValue(" - ");
    buttonPanel.getChildren().add(bDelete);
    Button bInfo = new Button();
    bInfo.setValue(" i ");
    buttonPanel.getChildren().add(bInfo);
    pGrid.getChildren().add(buttonPanel);
    comp.getChildren().add(pGrid);
}

@Override
public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
    DeliveryPeriodComponent deliveryComponent = (DeliveryPeriodComponent) component;
    DeliveryPeriod deliveryPeriod = new DeliveryPeriod();
    deliveryPeriod.setStartDate(deliveryComponent.getBegin());
    deliveryPeriod.setEndDate(deliveryComponent.getEnd());
    deliveryPeriod.setPlanningPeriodId(deliveryComponent.getPlanningPeriod());

    // Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    // String clientId = component.getClientId();
    // String value = params.get(clientId);
    // ((UIInput) component).setSubmittedValue(value);
}

@Override
public Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object submittedValue)
        throws ConverterException {
    Converter converter = getConverter(context, (DeliveryPeriodComponent) component);
    if (converter != null) {
        return converter.getAsObject(context, component, (String) submittedValue);
    } else {
        return submittedValue;
    }
}

private Object getValue(FacesContext context, DeliveryPeriodComponent comp) {
    Object submittedValue = comp.getSubmittedValue();
    if (submittedValue != null) {
        return submittedValue;
    }
    Object begin = comp.getBegin();
    Object end = comp.getEnd();
    Object planningPeriod = comp.getPlanningPeriod();
    DeliveryPeriod period = new DeliveryPeriod();
    period.setStartDate((String) begin);
    period.setEndDate((String) end);
    period.setPlanningPeriodId((Integer) planningPeriod);
    Converter converter = this.getConverter(context, comp);
    if (converter != null) {
        return converter.getAsString(context, comp, period);
    } else if (period != null) {
        return period.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

private Converter getConverter(FacesContext context, DeliveryPeriodComponent comp) {
    Converter conv = ((UIInput) comp).getConverter();
    if (conv != null) {
        ValueExpression exp = comp.getValueExpression("value");
        if (exp == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Class valueType = exp.getType(context.getELContext());
            if (valueType == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return context.getApplication().createConverter(valueType);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Maybe this is a trivial problem, I am not a pro at JSF and still learning. And it is very hard to write your own components when you almost confused about the basics :-( Still learning new things every day. Thank you for your help!

(I found a lot on custom components with examples like a custum inputfields, these components works well and transfer their data. Unfortunatly I found nothing on custom components which contains more then one input field or did something different from the existing JSF elements)

Comment: Looks like this is impossible to do. :-(
I changed to a component composite to do the stuff, but that isn't the solution for my other components. This component was intended to be the test case for the others and figure out, how to get multiple inputs.

Comment: I would be interested in this as well. But the last days I havent found anything.

Comment: I never finished this in this way, I used a JSF composite to write the component by using standard components. Here the component contains two 'calendar' objects and a 'selectOneMenu'.

Answer (score -1):

In Xhtml Page Call your listner with

```
<h:commandButton id="add" value="Add More" styleClass="input_right_cor" type="button">
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" listener="#{templateSearchHandler.AddRow}"  />
                </h:commandButton>
```

Comment: But there is now xhtml page and there is a add button, but this functionality isn't the problem here. It is all about saving the new input from the fields.